# Unwanted page change after clicking a delete link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I have created an HTML table.

It dynamically adds rows to the table and it has an option to delete the current row.

Each row is data from MongoDB. When I click the `delete` button, I want an item to be deleted from the database.

However, I am not able to create an HTML tag that will pass a link to the function without reloading the page.

My current method reloads the page after pressing the delete!

Here is my code: -

```js
$(document).submit( '#newProductForm', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Create data for submission to database
    let data = $('#newProductForm').serialize();
    console.log("Form submitted: " + data);

    $.post({
        url: '/admin/add',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done( response => {
        resetProductTable();
        console.log("Successfully added products to the database!")
    }).fail( function (response) {
        console.log('Error New Product: ' + response);
    })
})

//Gets all the products from the database
function getAllProducts(){
    $.ajax('/admin/all').done( function (data) {

        const productTable = $('#productsTable');
        if (productTable.css("visibility", "hidden")) {
            productTable.css("visibility", "visible");
        }
        productTable.css("visibility", "visible");
        $('#loadingMessage').remove();
        if (data) {
            data.forEach(element => {
                productTable.append(`<tr class="productRows"><td>${element.title}</td>
                                         <td>${element.description}</td>
                                         <td>${element.price}</td>
                                         <td>${element.shipping.timeNeeded}</td>
                                         <td>${formatTime(element.shipping.price)}</td>
                                         <td>${element.quantity}</td>
                                         <td>${element.DateAdded}</td>
                                         <td>${element.tags}</td>
                                         <td><a href="admin/edit/${element._id}">Edit</a></td>
                                         <td><a href="admin/delete/${element._id}" id="deleteLink">Delete</a></td>
                                    </tr>`);
            });
        } else {
            productTable.append(`No Products Found!`)
        }
        console.log("Leaving get all products!");
    })
}
```

How should I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

If you create `<a>` it is a link and then it is expected that it change the page:

- With HTML a `<a>` element can only trigger `GET` request, it is expected that it changes the page after it get the new one.
- You can still use `target="_blank"` `<A>` DOM attribute to open it in a new tab.

See as this example, it will try to change the page:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/admin/delete/124">Delete</a>
```

What you propably want is to call a `DELETE` method on your backend, for that you can only use `JavaScript` and some library for ajax such as `xhr` (low level) or `fetch` (high level).

If you want to use `<a>` element, you must stop the `event` propagation using javascript, for that, you have [Event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). You will also have to listen for click event on the `<a>` element:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', onDelete, false);
}

function onDelete(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // do whatever you want with the link
  console.log(e.target.href);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/admin/delete/124" id="deleteLink">Delete</a>
```

You can replace `<a>` with `<button>`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', onDelete, false);
}

function onDelete(e) {
  // do whatever you want with the link
  console.log(e.target.datasets.href);
}
```

```css
.btn-link {
  display: inline;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
  text-decoration-color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-link" type="button" data-href="https://www.google.com/admin/delete/124" id="deleteLink">Delete</button>
```

In your jQuery app even if it's obselete jQuery code, with `<a>` you would do this:

```js
// we don't need jQuery to write this but since it's there...
$(document).onload(function onload() {
  // bind the event from the whole page targeting all .btn-link elements 
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-link', function onClick(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stop the event so you don't change page
    // you don't need jQuery for AJAX, just use fetch:
    fetch(e.target.href, { method: 'DELETE' }); 
  });
});
```